# Ionic jasmine testing controller and scope undefined on it block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, jasmine

I am trying to create this unit testing using karma-jasmine for a existing Ionic 1 app; every is setup and running, but when I try my first test below both the var scope and controller are undefined; I already looked into several tutorials and blog but everything is like I did here.

status.tests.js

```
describe('statusController', function(){
    var $controller, scope;    
    beforeEach(module('clerk'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$controller_, $stateParams, $localStorage, $ionicPopup, 
            $cordovaGoogleAnalytics, $cordovaNetwork, ItemsService, OrdenService, ClientesService){

        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_('StatusCtrl', { $scope: scope });
        spyOn(scope, 'printReporte');
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        scope.$destroy();
    });    

    describe('cierre', function(){
        it('cierre ejecutado', function() {
            console.log('scope: ' + JSON.stringify(scope));
            console.log('controller: ' + JSON.stringify($controller));

            expect($controller).toBeDefined();
            expect(scope).toBeDefined();
            expect(scope.printReporte).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
        });    
    });
});
```

status.js

```
 angular.module('clerk.controllers')

 .controller('StatusCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $localStorage, $ionicPopup, 
    $cordovaGoogleAnalytics, $cordovaNetwork, ItemsService, OrdenService, ClientesService) {

    $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.trackView('status');

    $scope.printReporte = function(){      
        OrdenService.printReporte($scope.dataStorage.ordenes, $scope.productosVendidos, $scope.totalClientes, $scope.total);
    }
..........
})
```

console log

```
[vns@localhost clerk]$ gulp test
(node:30301) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[11:59:03] Using gulpfile ~/workspace/clerk/gulpfile.js
[11:59:03] Starting 'test'...
WARN `start` method is deprecated since 0.13. It will be removed in 0.14. Please use 
  server = new Server(config, [done])
  server.start()
instead.
20 05 2017 11:59:04.166:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
20 05 2017 11:59:04.167:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
20 05 2017 11:59:04.174:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
20 05 2017 11:59:04.432:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket cndxz1n_qRnaz85aAAAA with id 60468258
LOG: 'scope: undefined'
LOG: 'controller: undefined'
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) statusController cierre cierre ejecutado FAILED
    www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17918:53
    forEach@www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13691:24
    loadModules@www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17878:12
    createInjector@www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17800:30
    workFn@www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2922:60
    loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:162:17
    Expected undefined to be defined.
    tests/controllers/status.tests.js:26:44
    loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:162:17
    Expected undefined to be defined.
    tests/controllers/status.tests.js:27:38
    loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:162:17
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scope.printReporte') in tests/controllers/status.tests.js (line 28)
    tests/controllers/status.tests.js:28:25
    loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:162:17
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scope.$destroy') in tests/controllers/status.tests.js (line 18)
    tests/controllers/status.tests.js:18:14
    loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:162:17
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 2 (1 FAILED) (skipped 1) ERROR (0.048 secs / 0.016 secs)
[11:59:04] Finished 'test' after 911 ms
```

jasmine files

```
files: [
  'www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js',
  'www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'www/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js', 
  'www/lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.js',           
  'www/js/app.js',
  'www/js/controllers.js',
  'www/js/orden.js',
  'www/js/status.js',
  'www/js/cliente.js',
  'www/js/services/clientes.js',
  'www/js/services/items.js',
  'www/js/services/login.js',
  'www/js/services/orden.js',
  //'www/js/**/*.js',
  'tests/**/*tests.js'
]
```

using: 
ionic 1.3.1
jasmine 2.6.0
Node Version: 6.10.2

UPDATE:
karma config

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [      
  "www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js",
  "www/lib/angular/angular.js",
  "www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",      
  "www/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js", 
  'www/lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.js',           
  'www/js/app.js',
  'www/js/services/clientes.js',
  'www/js/services/items.js',
  'www/js/services/login.js',
  'www/js/services/orden.js',            
  'www/js/controllers.js',
  'www/js/orden.js',
  'www/js/status.js',
  'www/js/cliente.js',
  //'www/js/**/*.js',
  'tests/**/*tests.js'
]
```

Also changed $rootScope to **$rootScope** underscore for every injection.

app.js

```
angular.module('clerk', ['ionic', 'ionic.cloud','clerk.controllers', 'clerk.services', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCordova']) ....
```

Comment: and another thing: injecting angular stuffs in the beforeEach, you shuold wrap them with two underscore. so it's `_$rootScope_` not `$rootScope`.
Same for all the angular stuffs like `$stateParams`

Comment: In your karma.config file, it seems you included only the angular-mocks library. You should include also the angular one

Comment: Thanks, www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js I think it include angularjs; but I will try what you said anyway

Comment: try both please and let me know, also the injection with underscores, don't forget it

Comment: I try it both and still getting the same results also got this message: PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) LOG: 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.' Like I told you the ionic.bundle.js file includes angular

Comment: The problem is that error happens in beforeEach, and the error is swallowed. It's not possible to help you without seeing the error. Try to switch from Phantom to Chrome, this may help.

Comment: Yea, I notice that beforeEach is eating the error; I will try what you said.

Comment: @estus I tested it using the firefox and not error in console either

Comment: Try to catch it like `beforeEach(() => { try { inject(...); } catch (e) { console.error(e) } })` instead of `beforeEach(inject(...))`. I haven't meet this problem myself but it's quite common. It's not possible to help somehow without error message - unless you can provide a plunk/fiddle that runs Jasmine test and can replicate the problem.

Comment: @estus check the console log here: https://pastebin.com/MCNnREgu

Comment: what is in that line is this `throw $injectorMinErr('modulerr', "Failed to instantiate module {0} due to:\n{1}",
                  module, e.stack || e.message || e);`

Comment: This seems to be a problem loading the modules; please check my app.js and my controller module; because I have a main module 'clerk' and a submodule 'clerk.controllers' with all the controllers

Comment: Obviously, some modules are not there, otherwise the error wouldn't be there. `modulerr` error always contains the name of missing module, the reference to a line is not enough. Console output doesn't contain the error from beforeEach.   It's not possible to suggest anything else here without http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .